# Sum up Data BI Desktop by using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, sumifs

I have two tables, one table is oracle live 10-year sales journal, second table is Aug to Dec 2023 signed Turnover targets, now i wants to sum-up Turnover (By adding a column in second table of Aug to Dec 2023 singed targeted turnover in front of those customer whose are singed turnover targets) from oracle live 10 year sales journal based on given customer in second table of singed targeted Turnover Aug to Dec 2023.... i think it's just like sumifs in excel but how to perform in BI i have no idea.

Please guide me, the DAX formula which can help me to calculate this column field and it calculate turnover from live sales journal from Aug 2023 to Dec 2023.

Imported Info of Tables:

In 10 year live sales journal customer entries, dates, customer codes are repeated due again and again live invoices.

In Second table of Aug to Dec 2023 turnover customers entries like customer codes are unique and not repeated.

Image of live sales journal[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J98Wa.jpg)

Comment: is there a link between the 2 tables?

Comment: Does the second table have a date? I'd just create a Date dimension and join both tables to the Date table. then your data will roll up.

Comment: Yes both tables have a one to many relation.

Comment: Yes invoice date is available in sales journal. in targeted turnover table we dont have need for date bcz there just a qty of singed turnover.